# AWS Update all resource Tags based on a condition

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags

I am looking for some script which updates AWS resource tags on an account based on a given condition

Example - if existing resource tag key value = "xyz" then,update it to "abc"

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you would need to write a script to query tags per service of your interest, e.g. for EC2
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/describe-tags.html and then update the target tags by https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/create-tags.html

Comment: Thanks for your response.My requriement is to get something like the below -                  
 # Get the required tags
 
 client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi')
 output = client.get_resources(TagFilters=[
        {
            'Key': 'name',
            'Values': [
                'myname',
            ]
        },
    ],
   )
   
   # update the tags
   
  response = client.tag_resources ( need to pass this values from the above "output" )

Answer (score 0):

[HERE](https://github.com/nicomar2000/aws-tagger) is a little script I created in Python that I think would accomplish what you're looking for.

With this script, you would get a list of your resources, along with the missing tag suggestion based on the existing resource key, description, and resources ID.

Let's say you would like to make sure all your Security Group have the **Environment** tag.

So in the script, you add the tag key and you list all the possible values. At the same time each of those values has an associated list of "hint" words that if they are found in the resource's pre-existing tags, or the resource description or ID, the value would be added along with the tag key.

Also, if no value hint was found in the examined resource, the script would do the same examination to all the linked resources to the subject resource. So in this case is a Security Group, and a linked resource would be the VPC where this resource was built.

Once your happy with the tag value suggestion, you can select to apply in bulk or one by one the missing tags to your AWS resources.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).